# Unable to remove spacing before first column of cells and after last cell?

Tags: html, css

I am unable to remove the spacing before the Top Left & Bottom Left cells and after the Right cell.

I would like the cells to use the full width of the screen with border spacing only in the middle.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/yz9hqxjv/)

```css
#div-layout,
#div-layout-nested {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
#div-layout-nested {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.div-layout-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.div-layout-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ffb2b2;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-layout">
  <div class="div-layout-row">
    <div id="div-layout-nested">
      <div class="div-layout-row">
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Left</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Middle</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div-layout-nested">
      <div class="div-layout-row">
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Botom Left</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Bottom Middle</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Bottom Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-layout-cell">Right</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want this https://jsfiddle.net/e13dw9yk/ ?

Comment: You should consider remaking the Layout with a proper table, it doesn't look good

Answer (score 0):

You can get most of the way there, by adding:

```
body,
#div-layout,
.div-layout-row,
.div-layout-cell {
margin: 5px 0;
}

#div-layout,
.div-layout-row,
.div-layout-cell
#div-layout-nested {
border-spacing:0 0;
}
```

at the bottom of your styles.

I suspect you will find the table much easier to style if you rewrite it.

At present you have two `.div-layout-row`s, each nested within a `#div-layout-nested`, both of which themselves are nested within a `.div-layout-row`.

Three recommendations:

1. Reducing the nesting levels will make your table easier to style;
2. Consistently using `.class`es in favour of `#id`s - a good rule of thumb is never using `#id`s unless you absolutely have to - will also make your table easier to style;
3. Avoid giving different nesting levels the same `.class` - this will also make your table easier to style.

Here is your table again with the markup unchanged, but with the styles above added to the end of the stylesheet:

```css
#div-layout,
#div-layout-nested {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
#div-layout-nested {
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.div-layout-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.div-layout-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #ffb2b2;
}

body,
#div-layout,
.div-layout-row,
.div-layout-cell {
margin: 5px 0;
}

#div-layout,
.div-layout-row,
.div-layout-cell
#div-layout-nested {
border-spacing:0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-layout">
  <div class="div-layout-row">
    <div id="div-layout-nested">
      <div class="div-layout-row">
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Left</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Middle</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Top Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="div-layout-nested">
      <div class="div-layout-row">
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Botom Left</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Bottom Middle</div>
        <div class="div-layout-cell">Bottom Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-layout-cell">Right</div>

  </div>
</div>
```